# How do you get the tags from text in a Tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am struggling to find any documentation of how you get tags from text in a Tkinter text widget. The Canvas widget has a `gettags()` method. I would imagine the text widget has a similar method but I can't find anything.

How can I get a list of all tags used in a specific range of characters?

Comment: Did you try `tag_names()`?

Comment: Are you asking for how to get the tags for a specific character or range of characters, or a list of all tags used by the text widget?

Comment: Get the tags by a specific range of characters.

Comment: @acw1668 I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no command that can give you a list of tags for a *range* of characters, but there is a command to get the tags for a single character.  If you want a list of all tags used anywhere in a range of characters you can iterate over the characters with something like this:

```
def get_tags(start, end):
    index = start
    tags = []
    while text.compare(index, "<=", end):
        tags.extend(text.tag_names(index))
        index = text.index(f"{index}+1c")

    return set(tags)
```

If you have a string that has character 1.0 tagged with "foo", and 1.1 is tagged as "bar", then `get_tags("1.0", "1.1") will return ("foo", "bar") since each tag was used somewhere in that range.